# Print-to-screen log window

Tags: vb.net, stream

I have to run a process - through the execution of a batch script - which produces an output that is saved as a text file. Furthermore, I need to see this output on a form of the application of mine and, to do this, I've set an iterative timer which updates every second the content of a non-editable RichTextBox but I have two issues:

- Each time the timer stops and restarts, I need to create a copy the output file, since the file is used from another process and can't be loaded onto the software as it is;
- Creating and loading this text file may be honerous in terms of hardware capability, since this file may reach really big size (even more than 5 GB).

Here is the code I'm providing:

```
Private Sub Form9_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   [...]
    Me.Timer1.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).TotalMilliseconds
    Me.Timer1.Start()
End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Application.DoEvents()
        Dim p = Process.GetProcessesByName("fds2ftmi_win_64")
        Dim appPath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Form1.TextBox5.Text + "/HTAoutput.dat") Then
            If p.Count > 0 Then
                RichTextBox1.Refresh()
                My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(Form1.TextBox5.Text + "/HTAoutput.dat", Form1.TextBox5.Text + "/HTAoutemp.dat", Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption.OnlyErrorDialogs, FileIO.UICancelOption.DoNothing)
                RichTextBox1.LoadFile(Form1.TextBox5.Text + "/HTAoutemp.dat", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
                RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.TextLength
                RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
            Else
                Call Button3_Click(sender, e)
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

Is there a more efficient way to show this stream-writing onto my log-window?
Thanks all are gonna answer me

**EDIT 1:**
Here is the code I'm providing:

```
Dim p = Process.GetProcessesByName("fds2ftmi_win_64")
Dim appPath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)
Dim str As FileStream
str = File.Open(Form1.TextBox5.Text + "/HTAoutput.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Form1.TextBox5.Text + "/HTAoutput.dat") Then
    If p.Count > 0 Then
        RichTextBox1.LoadFile(str, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
        RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.TextLength
        RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
        Application.DoEvents()
    Else
        Call Button3_Click(sender, e)
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Does the other process fully lock the file? I would have thought not because I would think that that would prevent copying. If you can copy the file then I would think that you could read it, so maybe try opening the file for reading only and then you may not need the copy at all.

Comment: Why do you want to load the file once a second? If it doesn't change, there is no point and it it does change it won't be displayed long enough for a user to see it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I've edited the reported code since I've seen a little mistake. Anyway, if I try to directly load the output log file (HTAoutput.dat), I'm getting an error because the file is used from another process. For this reason I have to create a copy of the file each time. Nevertheless, if I try to open the abovementioned file with a textfile viewer (notepad++ or WordPad), the process stops because the output file becomes locked. Obviously the file changes while the process is running and for this reason I reload it every second. Is there a way to directly stream it on to the RichTextBox?

Comment: *"if I try to directly load the [...] file [...] I'm getting an error"*. How exactly did you try to open it? Did you specify that it should be opened for reading only and shared? I'm guessing not. I'm not 100% sure but, as I said, if the file could not be opened for shared reading then I don't think that it could be copied either.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I've tried to do it as follows: `RichTextBox1.LoadFile(Form1.TextBox5.Text + "/HTAoutemp.dat", RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)` In the code reported in the thread, HTAoutput.dat is the output file, instead HTAoutemp.dat is the temporary copy of the file I have to create each time in order to show the log. Is there a way to stream this file onto the RTB? Or do I have to update it as I'm doing with the timer?

Comment: So "no" then. That couldn't be any use to begin with, because that will just load the entire file as it is now. The whole point of opening the existing file is so that you can read new data as it arrives without having to read everything you've already got, over and over. Look at the `File.Open` method, which provides much more control over how the file is opened and returns a `FileStream`, allowing you to read only new data each time.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks for the suggestion. I've configured the File.Open method but in order to update the content of the RichTextBox I have to call it each time. Do I have to use the timer as I've already done?

Comment: You only have to open it once and that's the point. `File.Open` returns a `FileStream`. You can read to the end of that stream and keep it open. Whenever the file is written to by another process, that new data becomes accessible via that `FileStream`, so you simply read to the end again and that will get just the new data, which you can append to the text in your control. You open the file once and only read new data each time. That's the whole point: not reading the same large amount of data over and over. I haven't tested but that's my understanding, at least.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I've updated my code. Maybe I'm missing some settings, because, as previously said, I have to call the loading each time to see the output log window updates.

Comment: Stop calling `LoadFile` on the `RichTextBox`! Listen to what I'm saying: `File.Open` returns a `FileStream` and that is where you read the data from. You can put a `StreamReader` on top of it if you like, to make reading text easier. Each time you read you will get only the new data and then you append that to your `RichTextBox` or whatever.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I'm not very expert of this method, since I've never used it before. Could you provide me an example of what you're saying please? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple demonstration of opening a file once and continuing to read only new data as it is added to that file.

Create a new WinForms Application project with two forms. Add a `TextBox` and a `Button` to each form. Make the `TextBox` multiline on `Form1`. Add a text file to your project named Test.txt and set `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always`. Add some default text to the file. Add this code to `Form1`:

```vb
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private reader As StreamReader

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Open the file for reading and allow sharing.
        Dim filePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Test.txt")
        Dim strm = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)

        reader = New StreamReader(strm)

        'Read all available text and append to the existing text.
        TextBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd()

        Form2.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Read all available text and append to the existing text.
        TextBox1.AppendText(reader.ReadToEnd())
    End Sub

End Class
```

and add this code to `Form2`:

```vb
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim filePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Test.txt")

        'Write a new line of text to the file.
        File.AppendAllText(filePath, Environment.NewLine & TextBox1.Text)

        'Get ready for the next line of text.
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox1.Select()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Run the project and you'll see your default text in `Form1`. Enter some text into `Form2` and click the `Button`. Do that a few times. Now click the `Button` on `Form1`. Voila! Repeat that cycle and see the text you enter on one form magically appear on the other.

Now go back and examine the code more closely. You can see that `Form2` appends a line of code to the file each time you click the `Button`. `Form1` reads the initial contents of the file when it loads and displays that, but it keeps the file open. Each time you click the `Button`, it will read only the new data, i.e. only the data after where it previously read up to. It then appends that new text to the existing text in the `TextBox`.